# Format attribute of Java and Python in C

Tags: java, python, c

In Python, we could use the format attribute this way:

```
"Today is {}/{}/{}".format(self.day, self.month, self.year)
```

In Java, we could do the same:

```
MessageFormat.format("Today is {0}/{1}/{2}", this.day, this.month, this.year);
```

Is there an equivalent format attribute in C? Apart from the %d and %s things which are also present in Python along with the format attribute. The later has an advantage as it doesnt require specifying the type of the variable whether a number or a string or whatnot.

Comment: I don't think there is because type information cannot be retrieved from variable-length arguments in C.

Comment: *Is there an equivalent format attribute in C?* Yes. *Apart from the `%d` and `%s` things* I don't think so. You could (maybe) write such a feature with a preprocessing step.

Comment: I tried something that doesn't require explicit specifying the type of the variable [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485)

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done in C. Not cleanly, at least.

Both Java and Python have *strong typing*. This means that objects have an intrinsic type that cannot change, and this type is known during the execution of the program. You can transform any object to a string appropriately, because their types are known and they implement the `toString()`/ `__str__()` method.

C, in contrast, has *weak typing*. Types in C are more of an *interpretation* of the data at a memory address. You can cast anything to anything else. The `sprintf()` function has no way of knowing what's what.

There are ways of building strings with a generic syntax in C++, if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you so much.